# Adding text to image and save

Tags: c#, image-processing, text, save, digital

In my program i allow the user to enter some text which then gets put on top of an image using the `graphics.DrawString()` method. When i then go to save this image, it saves it without the text.

How can i save both as one image?

I have seen a few examples but none of which have helped.

```
private void txtToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(535, 50, original_image.Width, original_image.Height);
        Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\\PCB.bmp");

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(img);

        StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat();

        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        g.DrawString("Hellooooo", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White,
                r, strFormat); 

        image.Save("file_PCB.Bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are creating a graphics object without a canvas. You are drawing on nothing, so there is nothing that is changed by your drawing the text.

First create a copy of the image (or create a blank bitmap and draw the image on it), then create a graphics object for drawing on that image:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image_save);
```

Then draw the text and save the image.

Comment: I have created a test method. Is it something like this? although this does not work either. Updated Original Question.

Comment: @user1221292: Please don't remove so much from the original question, then the answers doesn't make any sense. The code that you have now is basically correct. From what I can tell, you are creating a rectangle that is as large as the image, but offset so that it's partially outside the image, then writing the text centered in that rectangle may very well mean that you are drawing the text outside the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code, we used it for watermark image.

```
System.Drawing.Image bitmap = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("image\\img_tripod.jpg")); // set image 

        Font font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        Point atpoint = new Point(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;


        graphics.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, atpoint, sf);
        graphics.Dispose();
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        m.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
```