# Draw text on top of an image and outside the image area

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, console-application

I want to draw a text on top of an image and outside the image area. By this, I mean to produce a new image with the new dimensions. To illustrate, I want to convert a picture like this:

[image: before adding text]

to something like this:

[image: after adding text]

Also, I want it to be transparent. i.e. the space between the image and text should be transparent. Any idea how I could do this in C# console app?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this depending on what you have (JPEG, PDF, BitMap, XAML) and what you want to output. None of which you have told us.

Comment: @DourHighArch I actually have both PNG and JPEG formats. It is mostly PNG images though. The output should also be in PNG and transparent.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It is for a C# console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do with the System.Drawing library from .net framework. You can do a lot with it. Here's a reference posting from stack overflow, [Adding text to image and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892308/adding-text-to-image-and-save)

But the long and short of it is:

1. Create a new blank image in system.drawing to lay your image into.
2. Lay your image into the blank image. ([How do I overlay an image in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068065/how-do-i-overlay-an-image-in-net))
3. Lay text in that same blank image, outside of your image overlay.

You are done!

Comment: So basically that means copying the image into a new image with the higher dimensions and adding the text afterward, right?

Comment: You got it! That's the way to do it. You have to create a bigger canvas to put the text into.